# Countdown timer in TextView when ViewPager change

Tags: java, android, timepicker

I have a Count down timer inside a timepicker dialog , i want the result to post in TextView also when change viewpager. 
It works only in the same page.

example code

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
    }

    public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: how you have start CountDownTimer in view pager

Comment: no i start CountDownTimer inside Fragment like this code: class MyClass extends AppCompatActivity {
**STUFF**
public CountDownTimer timer;
} and then inside fragment ((MyClass)getActivity()).timer.start();